# Unable to see TypeScript runner options while configuring runner in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I try to configure Default build task using the Global Tasks menu of my Visual Studio Code, I dont see the options related to typescript, I see only four options:-
MSBuild
Maven
.NetCore
Others
Here is the image of my VSCode IDE:-

[Vscode IDE Build Runner options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXWRO.jpg)

I have successfully installed typescript on my machine using
npm install -g typescript

Please someone point out what the issue can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose `Others`.

This is an example of MY `tsc` task runner:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "tsc",
            "command": "tsc --watch",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After you have that saved, you can start it with:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> Tasks: Run task -> `tsc`

Now each time you change and save any `*.ts`-file, it will run and retranspile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @user2337353 Please upvote/mark as answer if this helped you solve your problem.